# How can I turn this regular JavaScript function into something React.js can read

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm following along with a video to make a slideshow with JavaScript. I'm trying to figure out how I can implement this function from the video to React in create-react-app. I'm not too familiar with React but I think I shouldn't be trying to have "getElementsByClassname" in my function. What should I do to make this work?

I'm not sure where to call a function as you would in regular JavaScript, so I've been calling it with an onClick event. If anyone could help me with that as well, that would be amazing.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import './Showcase.css';

class Showcase extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.initGallery = this.initGallery.bind(this);
    }
    initGallery(){
        let slideIndex, slides, dots, captionText;
        slideIndex = 0;
        slides = document.getElementsByClassName('imageHolder');
        slides[slideIndex].style.opacity = 1;
        console.log('hello');
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <section onClick={this.initGallery} id="Showcase"> {/*CONTAINS ALL SLIDING IMAGES*/}
                <div className="captionHolder">
                    <p className="captionText">Caption Text</p>
                </div>
                <div className="imageHolder"> {/*HOLDS ALL IMAGES HERE*/}
                    <img src="https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/amos17_v2.jpg" alt="Amos-17 Mission"/>
                    <p className="captionText">Caption Text-01</p>
                </div>

                <div className="imageHolder"> {/*HOLDS ALL IMAGES HERE*/}
                    <img src="https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/v2_smallsatheader.png" alt="RideShare Missions"/>
                    <p className="captionText">Caption Text-02</p>
                </div>

                <div className="imageHolder"> {/*HOLDS ALL IMAGES HERE*/}
                    <img src="https://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/nasa_astronauts3.jpg" alt="NASA Astronauts on crew Dragon"/>
                    <p className="captionText">Caption Text-03</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Showcase;
```

Not getting any errors, I checked that the function was being called successfully by adding a console.log whenever the click event triggered the function. I'm simply not getting the desired result which is to take the className and turn the opacity to 1 which will make an image appear since it is set to opacity 0 in the CSS file.

Comment: Your code is working for me.

Comment: Can you paste what is there in class 'imageHolder'

Comment: It started working for me as well; however, could you tell me how I could call my galleryInit function in React without needing an event handler?

Comment: when you want to call it, if not on onClick event?

Comment: As soon as the page loads, it should be called on its own.

Comment: would calling the function inside of componentDidMount be the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can call the function inside componentDidMount if you want to call it on load of the page i.e. render of the page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using document.getElementByClassName you can create an ref over an tag and use it like this.myRef = React.createRef(); in your constructor and binding it to the tag this is the way to do in react. You can refer here

[React Refs and Dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: could you tell me how I could call my galleryInit function in React without needing an event handler?

Comment: @albert_anthony6 use lifecycle Components componenetDidMount() lifecycle method can be used to do so , it is called just after render() method is called.